# Power BI - How to use DirectQuery with Presto ODBC

Tags: odbc, powerbi, presto

## Issue

ODBC with Import Mode take a long time to load data from Presto Cluster and take another long time to upload .pbix(with whole datasets) to Power BI Server.

## Therefore

1. I have own self-built Presto Cluster. Is there a way to use `DirectQuery` feature with it?
2. Is `QubolePresto` Connector only work with Qubole Presto Cluster?
3. Are there any Presto ODBCs benefit with `DirectQuery`?

---

[image: QubolePresto]

Simba ODBC
[image: ODBJ]

Comment: did u solve this?

Comment: @tooptoop4 Currently, DirectQuery only works with **Qubole** Presto, so cannot use with On-Prem Presto.